# Ajax upload failing but impossible to catch any errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I use frontend jquery ajax script to send image on to a php backend script hosted by a slim framework app.
The process works for all images except a single one (attached).

The backend is supposed to send back a json object. With that particular image it triggers the 'fail' promise of the jquery ajax upload. 
When I log 'errorThrown' I get:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
```

It's possible I get this because the returned data is not json but html. Still it is irrational that it does it with one image only. I'm not able to catch any error in the process.

I think the goal here is to know what is the error. If you have a suggestion as a way to find the error in the chain, please advise.

Front end upload script:

```
$( function() {
    let idOfUploadedImage = null
    let maxAllowedImages  = 5


    // Use case: User clicks on the 'Upload your image' button: image is sent to the server.
    $( '.imageUploader' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // determine which image (field) is currently treated
        idOfUploadedImage = event.target.id

        let form     = $( '.blog-form' );
        let formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData( form[ 0 ] ) : null;
        let data     = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : form.serialize();


        $.ajax( {
            url        : '/image-attachment/upload-image',
            type       : form.attr( 'method' ),
            contentType: false, // obligatoire pour de l'upload
            processData: false, // obligatoire pour de l'upload
            dataType   : 'json', // selon le retour attendu
            data       : data
        } ).done( function( response ) {
            console.log( `Upload image success: ${idOfUploadedImage}` )
            console.log( response )
            console.log( numberOfImagesVisibleFieldsOnTheForm )

            // Store in corresponding hidden fieldpath of uploaded image as returned from server.
            $( `#path-${idOfUploadedImage}` ).val( response.path );

            // In case an image was sucessfully uploaded, we make sure the image count that determines
            // the number of image container to show stays sync.
            numberOfImagesVisibleFieldsOnTheForm++

            // Show thumbnail of uploaded file
            let field         = form.find( `input[name="${idOfUploadedImage}"]` );
            let files         = field[ 0 ].files;
            let image         = files[ 0 ];
            let $imagePreview = $( `#image-preview-${idOfUploadedImage}` ).show();
            $imagePreview.find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', window.URL.createObjectURL( image ) );


            // Check if we can still ad images. If so, show next image elements.
            if ( numberOfImagesVisibleFieldsOnTheForm > maxAllowedImages ) {
                console.log( "You can't add more images" )
            } else {
                $( `#container-image-${numberOfImagesVisibleFieldsOnTheForm}` ).show()
            }

        } ).fail( function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( errorThrown );
            // Reset field from which image caused the error
            resetUploadImageField( idOfUploadedImage )

            //if ( response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.error ) {
            //    alert( response.responseJSON.error );
            //}
        } ).always( function() {
            console.log( "Upload image process complete" );
        } );
    } );
} )
```

Backend script:

```
 namespace Rib\Src\Apps\ImageAttachment\ImageAttachmentControllers;

use Rib\Src\Apps\ImageAttachment\ImageAttachmentModel;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;


class UploadImage
{
    /**
     * Use case: user has clicked to upload via ajax a single image from the frontend. This is NOT
     * the entire blog post form submission.
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Response $response
     * @return Response
     */
    public function upload( Request $request, Response $response )
    {
        $imageModel = new ImageAttachmentModel();

        # Create image in temp dir. Return its information
        $tmpImageInfo = $imageModel->uploadImageInTempDir();

        # If there are any error with the image (not an image, too big....) treat the error
        $error = $tmpImageInfo[ 'error' ] ?? null;
        if ( $error ) {
            # Inform the frontend with error message
            return $response->withJson( $tmpImageInfo, 500 );
        }

        # Resize image and create its thumbnails in tmp directory
        $tmpImageInfo = $imageModel->resizeImageAndCreateThumbnails(
            $tmpImageInfo[ 'tmpSaveTargetPlusImageName' ],
            $tmpImageInfo[ 'imageNameWithoutExtension' ],
            $tmpImageInfo[ 'imageOriginalExtension' ] );


        // At this point array $tmpImageInfo = "201703/e-1490022600.jpg"


        # We pass back to the frontend the final path of the image which will be in the form of:
        # 'yearmonth/filename-random.ext' . Note that currently image is NOT in its final
        # destination. It will have to be moved there when user finally posts the full form.
        return $response->withJson( $tmpImageInfo );
    }
}
```

Image culprit: 
EDIT: The upload WORKS with the image when I grab it back from stackoverflow, but not the original from my computer. I tried rename it and move it locally: it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please post the response from the upload ajax call. The issue is that the JSON returned from the server isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Willing to bet you have an error page and not JSON being returned, open up the network panel and look to see what the error is.

Comment: @NirajShah This helped. Indeed I was able to see in the response text the catch all exception var dump that I had set but that I couldn't see because of the ajax call. It turns out the error is: 'exif_read_data(e-1490024361.jpg): Illegal IFD size'. Now I must investigate this.

Comment: As I was able to catch the error you can propose the solution as answer. I might open a new issue if I can't solve the exif problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a 'exif_read_data(e-1490024361.jpg): Illegal IFD size'. problem happening on very specific images. I had a global exception handler but I couldn't get the error because post ajax call you can't render anything on the screen. As suggested i was able to get to it from reading the response text in the browser network utilities.

I then excluded treatment of this particular error from my exception and error handlers and script was able to run fine.